# Как делают оплату через мобильные приложения?

Tags: мобильные-приложения, платежи

У меня есть задача сделать приложение с возможностью оплаты прямо из него, в какую сторону копать ? Если есть возможность то предоставьте ссылки на сервисы организующие подобные услуги ?

Причем оплата интересует с карты а не по смс. т.е. пользователь вводит данные карты с нее списываются деньги, далее пользователь получает подтверждение оплаты.

Пояснение:
Меня интересует Существует ли сервис который предоставляет API который можно было бы интегрировать в мое приложение. Что бы в итоге пользователь напрямую из моего приложения смог бы совершать покупки?

Answer (score 1):

Есть сервисы такие как Payler, Робокасса, PayOnline и ряд других. Также наверняка подобные возможности могут предоставить некоторые банки.

К сожалению, в данном вопросе очень много нюансов. Поэтому конкретно подсказать что-либо сложно. Особенно при столь общей постановке вопроса. Так, что детали уже уточняйте сами в соответствующей документации или техподдержке.

Comment: На сколько я понял из описания этих платежных сервисов - они работают с сайтами. А меня интересует есть ли сервис который предоставляет API который можно было бы интегрировать в мое приложение. Что бы в итоге пользователь напрямую из моего приложения смог бы совершать покупки?

Comment: `WebView` никто не отменял. Да и если поискать, можно найти сервисы, которые предоставляют соответствующие API . По запросу "android оплата api" гугл сразу выдаёт, как минимум, Google Pay и Яндекс кассу.